# Primefaces confirmation dialolog in tab view does not hide after action is fired

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have got an issue with my confirmation dialog. It just does not close after clicking the confirm-button. This only occurs, if my form is in a tab view. (Excatly the some code works fine, if my form is not in a tab view but only a panel or something like that.)

```
        <h:form id="timingTableForm">
            <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{requestBean.rmRequest.timingList}" id="timingDataTable" editable="true">
             // some dataTable 
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:confirmDialog closable="true" appendToBody="true" id="confirmDialog" message="#{msg.conf_deleteyesno}" header="#{msg.conf_header}" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">  
                <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="#{msg.btn_yessure}" update="timingTableForm" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" actionListener="#{requestBean.deleteTiming}" process="@this"/>  
                <p:commandButton id="decline" value="#{msg.btn_notyet}" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />   
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </h:form>
```

If I change "oncomplete" to "onclick" it works fine also, but I want the dialog to disapear not until the server side operation is finished.

When I push the confirm-button something strange happens within the resulting HTML:

```
<div id="mainTabView:timingTableForm:confirmDialog" class="ui-confirm-dialog ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-overlay-hidden ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="width: auto; height: auto;">

<div id="mainTabView:timingTableForm:confirmDialog" class="ui-confirm-dialog ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-overlay-visible" style="width: auto; height: auto; left: 994.5px; top: 186px; visibility: visible; z-index: 1006;">
```

A new div with the same ID as my confirm-dialog is rendered. The result is one hidden confirm diolog (as expected) but there is also a new dialog that is still visible. 
If i push the confirm button again I have 2 hidden conform dialogs and 1 visible dialog and so on...

Am I doing something wrong? Can you spot any error? Or could this be a bug in primefaces?

- Primefaces 3.4.1
- Running on GlassFish 3.1.2
- Browser Firefox 16.0.2

Thank you in advance,
Fant

---

**Actually i found a solution for my problem:**

The problem only occurs, if I try to update the whole form which also contains the confirm dialog. If I only update some specific areas in this form, it works fine.

Comment: Why not move your confirmDialog outside the tabView ?

Comment: It's not possible to do this here because of some template design, but thanks anyway for your comment. I finnaly found a solution for my problem here. I'm not allowed to update the whole form, but if i update each single child within this form (except the dialog), everything works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dialog should not be placed inside any form, but be placed outside any form and have its own form.

```
<h:form id="timingTableForm">
    <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{requestBean.rmRequest.timingList}" id="timingDataTable" editable="true">
     // some dataTable 
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<p:confirmDialog closable="true" appendToBody="true" id="confirmDialog" message="#{msg.conf_deleteyesno}" header="#{msg.conf_header}" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">  
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="#{msg.btn_yessure}" update="timingTableForm" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" actionListener="#{requestBean.deleteTiming}" process="@this"/>  
        <p:commandButton id="decline" value="#{msg.btn_notyet}" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />   
    </h:form>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

This because the HTML representation of the dialog may in the real HTML DOM tree be moved outside the current form (as you explicitly did by `appendToBody="true"`), which may cause "wtf" behaviour during asynchronous requests and updates, as you're experiencing.

Comment: You are right, it is outside the current form in the resulting HTML, but I didn't expect that this could be a problem, because the correct form is submitted by the generated JavaScript. The reason why i put this dialog into the first form is, that i have to submit some additional data from inside this form. But I can handle this with some hiddin input field. Thank you, Fant

Comment: Or just use a view scoped bean. Multiple forms in the same view will refer the same view scoped bean instance anyway.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the point. The problem is, that this data is not submitted unitl I push the confirm button. So if I will use two forms, either I have to submit the first one too (via some JS), or I have to put this data in the second form (for the confirm dialog), don't I?

Comment: Just set the data when the action is invoked which should open the confirm dialog and (if necessary) clear out the data when cancel is called in confirm dialog.